# Missing Part of Speech? Gender Neutral third person pronoun

Tags: genderless-pronouns

Is there a gender neutral third person pronoun in English? Say I wanted to tell someone to "forward the email to him/her". Is there a word to replace "him/her" if the gender is unknown? Perhaps "them"?

Comment: "Them " would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

There have been [proposals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#Historical_and_dialectal_gender-neutral_pronouns) for various gender-neutral pronouns put forward from time to time, but "they/them" has become the de facto standard gender-neutral pronoun. It can be used if the gender is unknown ("Each person should give their best"), if the gender wants to be kept undisclosed ("I have a meeting after work and I'm meeting them at the bar"), etc.